# Slurm: how does a job's code reaches the compute nodes?

Tags: slurm

I want to understand how a job's code or application reaches the allocated computer node by using `--srun` or even nodes if I use MPI in slurm?

I read that clusters usually have shared filesystems. Does it mean that the  nodes just get the code for the job from a shared filesystem or do the nodes communicate directly with each other?

Unfortunately i didn't find information about it in slurm's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slurm will make the assumption that the paths to the files that are needed (code, as well as configuration files and data) are accessible in the same way from all compute nodes.

Typically, a cluster is equipped with a network filesystem (e.g. NFS) that is mounted on all login and compute nodes. It is often the home directory of the users, that is the directory in which the user is 'placed' when connecting. It is meant for code, executables, and small files.

Clusters also often offer another filesystem, a parallel filesystem (e.g. Lustre, BeeGFS, etc.) that is also mounted on all compute node. Often, the parallel filesystem is faster than the network filesystem, but it is less 'safe'; no backups, no snapshots, etc. It is meant to temporary data.

Comment: thank you. but what is the `sbcast` flag for then? is it just there for the cases without shared filesystems or is it useful in other situations too?

Comment: The `sbcast` command is useful when there is the need to copy a file on the local scratch disk space of the compute node. It is an alternative to using `cp` or `scp` in a  `for` loop. It may or may not be faster than a parallel filesystem. It depends on the number of nodes, file size, etc. But nevertheless, it avoid having to write the `for` loop.